# convert nvarchar sql server data type to number in ssis

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have one column in sql server DB having nvarchar data type and i want to put this table data to excel file,but it showing text data in the excel file.my requirement is to convert the sql server nvarchar column to numeric data type in ssis so that correct format(number format) can be insert into the destination excel file.Please let me know how i can do this.i tried with this approach use data conversion transformation and select eight byte signed ineteger data type ,but its not working.Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please if anyone know the solution for this,please reply it..Many thanks in advance.

Comment: and what error are you getting? It is highly likely that the data is not convertable to int becasue it doesn't contain only int data.

Comment: i'm not getting any error while using the derived column,but still data is not getting converted into numeric in the destination excel file

Comment: But the data is going inthere or is the column blank?

Comment: Did you re-map the Excel output to use the new column?  Usually the converted column will be called something like "Copy of {Original}".  In the Excel output dataflow transformation, go to "Mappings" and make sure the new field is the one being exported.

Comment: data is going into the column but in the text format..

Comment: Hi kevin,yes i have done the remapping with the newly created column.its not giving any error but data is in the text format inserted in the excel sheet..

Comment: I assume the Excel spreadsheet that you are outputting to already exists...?  Maybe the column is already formatted as "Text"?  Go into the Excel spreadsheet and format the column as number, then try to do the export again.

Comment: tried with this approach also,didn't work it..

Comment: is there any other way to do this seems impossible task??

Comment: Any luck on my request?

Answer (score 0):

In a SSIS dataflow task you can use the **Data Conversion** transformation to convert a nvarchar data type to an integer. You must ensure that data you want to convert does not contain data other than numeric values or you will run into issues. If this is not working please post a the specific error message you are receiving as this is the correct approach to converting data types in an SSIS package.